# MVC - Excel download on button click Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Firstly, I know there are multiple posts related to this error but nothing is helping so far.

I am getting an error "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent." in my MVC razor application when I make a call to SomeController.

How do I fix this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeController(Object abc)
{
    Helper.somemethod("","excel");

    return View(abc);//I tried this
    return RedirectToAction("SomeController"); //I tried this also
}

public static void somemethod(string settocken, string filenames, List<Sample> samples)
{
    //Extra logic for excel that uses List<Sample> to generate excel.

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("downloadToken", settocken));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", filenames));
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            book.Save(ms);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain step by step what behavior you trying to achieve from user's perspective?

Comment: I have Export button in my View, when user clicks on it I am exporting the data to excel (file download prompt) and the same time after file download I want to redirect to view and show the data there.

Answer (score 0):

@CoolArchTek http communication loop will be ended after HttpContext.Current.Response.End() call, so you can't add anything after that, however as far as I know there is no possibility in http to do what you want, so I would recommend you render your view with javascript which will initiate file download by client's browser

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, have an iframe inside view where you want to redirect to and show the data. And set the excel file path(or the action which returns excel file) as source for that iframe.

With this, as soon as the page loads, download begins.
Hope it helps.